# Redirect autoplay videos to site page

Tags: jquery, html, redirect, video.js, autoplay

My autoplay is working however I can't get the video to redirect to a page on my site? I need users to be able to see the video play for a few seconds and then it takes them to the home page of my site.

This is the code I am writing:

```
<ul>
  <li class="Video" id="video-1">
    <video autoplay id="video-background" muted>
      <source src="videos/brain_loop.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="videos/brain_loop.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
  videojs("videos/brain_loop.mp4").on("ended", function() {
    window.location = "http://www.example.com/home.html";
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please give us some specifics on the issue? Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: Hi Brett, thanks for the input, no Im not seeing any errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to your actual video id. For example if your ID of your `<video>` is `video-background` the following code will work.

```
videojs("video-background").on("ended", function() {
  window.location = "http://www.example.com/home.html";
});
```

This will ensure videojs knows which video you are referring to.

Comment: Heya tried what you said, but once the video finishes it just freezes on that page and doesn't redirect: 
<ul>
  <li class="Video" id="videos/brain_loop.mp4">
    <video autoplay id="videos/brain_loop.mp4" muted>
      <source src="videos/brain_loop.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="videos/brain_loop.ogg" type="video/ogg">

    </video>

  </li>
</ul>

<script>
videojs("videos/brain_loop.mp4").on("ended", function() {
  window.location = "http://www.example.com/home.html";
});
</script>

Comment: @Xana Can you try changing your ID? Just make it one word to test. Not sure if you can have periods and slashes in IDs.

Comment: @Xana just take the exact same code you had. But replace those 3 lines in your script tag with what I posted. It worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Heya, its not working for me at all. Still wont redirect. Will do some more searching into the problem thanks for all your previous input!

Comment: @Xana Is the function even being run? Try adding a console log and see if it’s being run

Comment: No response at all

Comment: @Xana Can you link a JSFiddle or something or link all of your current code?

Comment: @Xana This totally worked for me. So I'm not sure why it's not working for you.